# Quiero verificar en Python si una palabra de un input existe en un vector

Tags: python

Intento verificar si un string contiene las palabras de un array, para dar una respuesta al respecto.

Aqui el código con el que estaba probando:

```
  print("Prueba para determinar palabras")

  #El vector con las palabras que deseo verificar
  claves=['hambre', 'comida']
  mensaje=[]

  msj = input("Digita una oracion: ")

  #Esto separará las palabras del input
  mensaje2 = msj.split()

  mensaje.append(mensaje2)

  print (mensaje)

  cont = 0
  print("")
  if mensaje[cont] in claves:
    print("Mañana te cocino")
    cont = cont + 1

  else:
    print("Ok")
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tienes que recorrer la lista de palabras e ir una a una comprobando si está en `claves`, no implementas ningún ciclo en tu código. No me queda muy claro la función de la variable `mensaje`... ¿Quieres almacenar en el varios "mensajes" y luego iterar uno a uno para validarlos? Ahora mismo solo lo usa para almacenar un mensaje, creando una lista de listas `mensaje = [['Hola', 'soy', 'un', 'mensaje']]`, si solo vas a tratar con uno o los validas uno a uno según se ingresan usa simplemente `mensaje2` ...

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres saber si alguna de las palabras contenidas en `claves` se encuentra en la cadena recién ingresada debes recorrer la lista generada por `str.split` e ir comprobando una a una cada palabra:

```
print("Prueba para determinar palabras")
claves = ['hambre', 'comida']
msj = input("Digita una oracion: ")
mensaje = msj.split()

for palabra in mensaje:
    if palabra in claves:
        print("Mañana te cocino")
        break
else:  # Si el ciclo se ha completado (no se ha ejecutado break)
    print("Ok")

input()
```

Dado que supongo que no pretendes contar las veces que aparece una palabra prohibida es buena idea romper el ciclo en el instante en el que se encuentra una coincidencia (*short circuiting*), para ello se usa `break`.

Otra forma de hacer esto es usando el built-in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) junto a un generador que itere igualmente sobre la lista y realice la comprobación de pertenencia con `in`. `any` retorna `True` si al menos uno de los valores del iterable es evaluado como verdadero.

Por otro lado, si claves en vez de una lista es un conjunto (`set`) el proceso será considerablemente más eficiente al usar una tabla hash para la búsqueda, en vez de tener que recorrer toda la lista `claves` al completo cada vez que se hace `palabra in claves`:

```
print("Prueba para determinar palabras")
claves = {'hambre', 'comida'}
msj = input("Digita una oracion: ")
mensaje = msj.split()

if any(palabra in claves for palabra in mensaje):
    print("Mañana te cocino")
else:
    print("Ok")

input()
```

Comment: Como curiosidad, ¿crees que merece la pena en términos de eficiencia plantear una intersección de conjuntos? O sea `if set(mensaje).intersection(claves):` Desde luego es menos legible...

Comment: Me respondo yo mismo. Si `mensaje` fuera ya un conjunto, entonces `mensaje.intersection(claves)` es como el doble de rápido que el `any()`, pero ya que no lo es, la conversión a conjunto implica de todas formas un bucle implícito que hace que tarde en total lo mismo, o un pelín más.

Comment: En Python no siempre es fácil medir eficiencia sin test reales, teóricamente  `any` + `set` en realidad repite muchos pasos de `set(entry).intersection(claves)`, `in` ocasiona la llamada a `set_contains_key`, que genera el hash para el item y llama a `set_contains_entry`  sobre `claves`que es lo que hace `set.intersection`.  Por tanto, en ambos iteramos sobre la lista completa en el peor de los casos como comentas y generamos el hash para cada elemento, solo que `any` evita la creación de dos nuevos conjuntos, lo cual es importante, en especial si la entrada fuera extensa con pocos duplicados.

Comment: El mismo `any` (y el generador) crea también su sobrecarga al comprobar si cada elemento generado es `True` pero tiene una importante ventaja, deja de iterar en el instante que encuentra una coincidencia, cosa que al construir el conjunto no podemos evitar. En la mejor situación para `any` (primer elemento retorna `True`)  solo se itera sobre el primer elemento de la lista, mientras que `set(entry)` itera si o si sobre toda. Para el peor de los casos (no coincidencias) posiblemente para `set(entrada)` pequeños la diferencia sea inapreciable.

Answer (score 1):

La forma mas rápida seria usando

```
 if any(word in msj for word in claves):
```

de acuerdo a tu código obtiene lo que escribes y lo convierte en un arreglo para obtener las palabras y buscar la coincidencia en el array `['hambre', 'comida']`.

Como ejemplo si escribo `hola soy Kemill y tengo hambre`, obtendría las palabras y determinaría que se encuentra una de las palabras en el array:

```
[['hola', 'soy', 'Kemill', 'y', 'tengo', 'hambre']]
```

y de esta forma imprimiría:

```
Manana te cocino
```

---

ejemplo en tu código:

```
print("Prueba para determinar palabras")

#El vector insultos con las palabras que deseo verificar
claves=['hambre', 'comida']
mensaje=[]

msj = input("Digita una oracion: ")

#Esto separará las palabras del input
mensaje2 = msj.split()

mensaje.append(mensaje2)

print (mensaje)

if any(word in msj for word in claves):
    print("Manana te cocino")    
else:
    print("Ok")
```